# Convert Lat/Lon to MGRS

Tags: c#, math, gis, coordinates, coordinate-systems

Does anyone know where I could find a library of code for converting Lat/Lon position to [Military Grid Reference System (MGRS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system)?  I'm looking for a C# implementation if possible.

Comment: You may want to consider asking these forms of questions on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ended up using [GeoTrans](http://geotranz.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.4.2/dirs.html) and create a DLL from the code and using PInvoke to call the functions.
We pulled the following from the source incase anyone wanted to know (minimal solution):

- polarst
- tranmerc
- ups
- utm
- mgrs

The PInvoke Signature we used:

```
[DllImport("mgrs.dll")]
public static extern int Convert_Geodetic_To_MGRS(
   double Latitude,
   double Longitude,
   int Precision, // 1 to 5, we used 4 (10 square meters)
   StringBuilder MGRS);
```

which corresponds to this function in mgrs.h:

```
MGRSDLL_API long __stdcall Convert_Geodetic_To_MGRS(
   double Latitude,
   double Longitude,
   long Precision,
   char* MGRS);
```

Comment: Hi could you share the PInvoke dll you created?

Comment: @SwDevMan81 can you please share the DLL? And the way how can i add it to my windows phone project

Answer (score 3):

[CoordinateSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoordinateSharp/) is available as a Nuget package and can do just that.

```
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(40.57682, -70.75678);
c.MGRS.ToString(); // Outputs 19T CE 51307 93264
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GDAL](http://gdal.org/)'s C# wrappers to convert from lat/lon to UTM.  You then just need to format the values appropriately for MGRS, since it's just UTM with a different numerical format.

Answer (score 2):

Found on js if it's help...

https://github.com/codice/usng.js

usage-

```
var converter = new usngs.Converter();
alert(converter.LLtoMGRS(33.754032, -98.451233, 9));
```